# POLLY Nuget Package WaitAndRetryAsync Method

Tags: polly

I am using Polly nuget package to utilize its Retry feature for webAPI/WCF calls in my project.

I am just curious to know what is maximum duration of wait we can give for `WaitAndRetryAsync` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polly imposes no limit on the wait in wait-and-retry.  The maximum duration of wait you can specify is therefore [`Timespan.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue.aspx) (which is probably more than you need ;~).